# Equivalent in yum of apt-get update

Tags: yum, rhel, apt, package-managers

In Debian derivatives, before installing software from apt using `apt-get install xxx`, it is necessary to run `apt-get update`.  This refreshes the package lists so that dependencies are resolved correctly, etc.

When using an RHEL instance, out of habit, I ran `yum update` before installing software.  However, this was only to find that `yum update` *upgraded* all of my packages instead of, or possibly in addition to, updating package lists locally as in `apt-get update`.

Is it necessary to update yum's package lists before running `yum install xxx`?  If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Probably better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most yum commands will refresh the cache automatically if needed. It works differently than apt, which will not update its cache unless the update command is run